# Port numbers that Dialog Flow agent runs on

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am developing a simple chatbot using the DialogFlow agent and using the web interface to communicate to the agent.

I want to bind it to the existing web portal which runs behind a firewall. So, my question is on which port numbers does the Dialog Flow agent communicates with so that I can open those specific ports on the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify this in your Fulfillment webhook call.  Otherwise HTTPS defaults to 443, and http to 80.

https://yourdomainname:port/url

https://yourdomainname.com:5000/webhookpageserverurl
(will open up to port 5000)

Training

http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/2.html